# In HIGHCHARTS unable to set the max point in the gauge

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I'm using HIGHCHARTS solid gauge, with min - 0 and max - 18, while setting max value to 18 its showing 20.

The speedgauge should be between -0 to 18
My field level is storing in double data type.

op- max 20
expected op - max 18

code

```
var chartSpeed = Highcharts.chart('container-speed', Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
                yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    max: 18.0,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Filled'
                    }
                },
                    credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                    series: [{
                    name: 'Speed',
                    data: [@Model[0].filled.ToString("N2")],
                    dataLabels: {
                        format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px;color:' +
                        ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') + '">{y}</span><br/>' +
                        '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver">Feet</span></div>'
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        valueSuffix: ' km/h'
                    }
                }]

                    }));
                    var a = @System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["8"];
                    var chartRpm = Highcharts.chart('container-rpm', Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
                        yAxis: {
                            min: 0,
                            max: 100,
                            title: {
                                text: 'Filled %'
                            }
                        },
                                series: [{
                            name: 'Filled %',
                           data: [(@Model[0].filled)/ a * 100],
                            dataLabels: {
                                format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px;color:' +
                                ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') + '">{y:.1f}</span><br/>' +
                                '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver">% Percentage</span></div>'
                            },
                            tooltip: {
                                valueSuffix: 'Percentage'
                            }
                        }]
                   }));

            setInterval(function () {
                           var point,
                    newVal,
                    inc;
    }, 2000);
```

Comment: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved your problem with adding a `tickPositioner` function to the gauge, which returns the `min` and `max` value as a position, solving the tickInterval issue you are most likely facing. This will make the y-axis code look the following:

```
 yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 18,
    tickPositioner: function() {
      return [this.min, this.max];
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Speed'
    }
  },
```

I have a working sample derived from the Highcharts demo [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NMwRar). It doesn't include your code as a lot of it was missing for me to reproduce it, but it shows a max of 18 on the speed gauge.